# Regex capaz de ignorar os prefixos de uma palavra

Tags: python, regex

Tenho essas regex a seguir:

```
regex_list = [ 
    '(?:arquiv|auto)(\w+) (?:auto|arquiv) (?:definitiv)',
    '(?:arquiv|auto)(\w+) (?:auto|arquiv)',
    '(?:arquiv)(\w+) (?:definitiv)'
]
```

Meu o objetivo é capturar frases como: "arquivados os autos", "autos arquivados", "arquivamento definitivo", etc.

Só que quando coloco **desarquivamento** a regex também captura.  As frases podem vir também como: `"arquive-se, portanto, os autos, de modo definitivo"`.

Gostaria de saber como faço para ignorar os termos que vierem com prefixos (nesse caso, "desarquivamento", só quero palavras com prefixo *arquiv.*) e garantir que frases como essa última também sejam capturadas.

Comment: Expressão regular não parece ser a solução para o seu problema - até porque pelo visto as expressões não são regulares. Por que não utiliza alguma ferramenta de processamento natural de linguagem? Leia sobre NLTK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar `\b`, que é uma *word boundary* (na falta de uma tradução melhor, é algo como "fronteira entre palavras"). Basicamente, serve para indicar posições da string que possuem um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa).

Por exemplo, colocando um `\b` antes do `arquiv`, você já elimina o caso do "desarquivamento".

Para os demais casos, não ficou muito claro todas as variações que a frase pode ter, mas pelo que entendi, os critérios são:

- pode ter "arquiv" ou "auto"
- pode ou não ter "arquiv" ou "auto" logo depois
- "definitivo" é opcional
- entre essas palavras pode ter zero ou mais palavras

Dá para fazer em uma regex só:

```
import re

frases = [
 "arquivados os autos",
 "autos arquivados",
 "arquivamento definitivo",
 "desarquivamento definitivo",
 "arquive-se, portanto, os autos, de modo definitivo"
]

r = re.compile(r'\b(?:arquiv|auto)(\w+).*?(?:auto|arquiv)?.*?(?:definitiv)?')
for frase in frases:
    if r.search(frase):
        print('encontrou a frase {}'.format(frase))
```

A regex encontra todas as frases, exceto a que tem "desarquivamento". `.*?` é "zero ou mais caracteres", garantindo que pode ter qualquer coisa entre as palavras desejadas.

E os `?` logo depois dos parênteses tornam todo o trecho opcional, assim, tanto o segundo parênteses (com `auto|arquiv`) quanto o terceiro (com `definitiv`) são opcionais.

---

Lembrando que essa regex é bem "ingênua" e propensa a falsos-positivos, dependendo de quão complexas forem as frases que você quer avaliar. Dependendo do que você quer fazer, talvez seja melhor seguir a [recomendação que o Anderson deu nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369945/regex-capaz-de-ignorar-os-prefixos-de-uma-palavra#comment736523_369945)

Comment: Grato, @hkotsubo. Na verdade, estou experimentando alternativas. Dependendo de como as coisas irão, mudarei a abordagem para melhor atender o problema. Mas suas instruções serviram para o que eu precisava no momento.

Answer (score 0):

Com este regex você consegue algo parecido:

`(autos?)|((?<!\w)arquiva(dos)?|(\-se)?)`

[Aqui](https://regex101.com/r/aRTJMm/1) você pode executar

O segredo aqui é o `look behind`, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) explica bem.

`(?<!\w)` significa: olhe para trás e veja se tem uma palavra(conjunto de caracteres), se tiver, não corresponda.

Esse regex pode não estar 100%, mas creio que vá te ajudar.